# Colors in new matlab graphics subsystem

Tags: matlab

Is there a comprehensive way to reproduce plots - i.e. line colors - generated by the "old graphics subsystem" as good as possible when using matlab 2015? (I have some old plots as bitmaps, and the visual impression of newly generated ones should fit for presentations).

Thanks!

Comment: By ML, I'm assuming you mean MATLAB?

Comment: Which colors do you mean? Colormaps for images? Line colors?

Comment: Do you have any old .fig files?

Comment: I always look at ML and go: Machine Learning

Comment: @GameOfThrows that is what I thought too... Which is why I asked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics_transition/why-are-plot-lines-different-colors.html) at mathworks, describes how to do what you want.  The following lines will set the colors to the "old" color order.

```
co = [0 0 1;
      0 0.5 0;
      1 0 0;
      0 0.75 0.75;
      0.75 0 0.75;
      0.75 0.75 0;
      0.25 0.25 0.25];
set(groot,'defaultAxesColorOrder',co)
```

Comment: Yes, i saw that page. But is ther a way to change the behavoir of the plot subfunctions so that ax.ColorOrderIndex is reset in a compatible way (without me having to reset it manually)?

Comment: The above, is how you change the behavior of the plot function.  Alternatively, you can override the plot function with your own plot function.  I have a custom figure function I use all the time, which this kind of thing would integrate well into.

Comment: Yes, i may go that way.